# Operator and template

Tags: c++

Can somebody help me? Im getting this error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'Rectangle')

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T higher(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

class Rectangle
{
    private:
        double a,b;
    public:
        Rectangle(double x, double y)
        {
            a=x;
            b=y;
        }
        double GetP()
        {
            return a*b;
        }
        friend bool operator>(Rectangle, Rectangle);
};

bool operator>(Rectangle p1, Rectangle p2)
{
    if(p1.GetP() > p2.GetP())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



int main()
{
    Rectangle p1(2,4),p2(3,6);
    cout << higher(p1,p2) << endl;
}
```

It has to print higher surface of 2 rectangles. I cant figure out problem.

Comment: You need to define a `operator <<` for you type if you want to be able to `cout` it.

Comment: Did you mean `cout << higher(p1,p2).getP()`? You say you want to print the higher surface, to get surface of `Rectangle` object you have `getP()` function.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks!